# No operating system found when booting from USB

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, recovery-disk

I have a Dell Inspiron N4010 laptop running Phoenix BIOS. I downloaded the Windows 7 x64 ISO to create a bootable USB. I did this under OS X by following the instructions from this website: http://blog.lewan.com/2012/02/10/making-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-an-apple-mac-os-x-from-an-iso/

I downloaded the ISO from here: http://mirror.corenoc.de/digitalrivercontent.net/

I changed the boot settings on the Dell to make the USB the first to boot, but I get the no operating system found. The USB is UDF formated. The reason I did this on a mac is because I don't have the Windows recovery CD and I can't boot into Windows.

Comment: if you hit F12 just after POST, but before boot, does your USB volume appear in the boot list?

Comment: Are you booting in compatability/legacy mode?  Did you make a EFI installation media?

Comment: Yes, I get USB storage and Removable Disk. I tried both but I get no operating system found. @Ramhound I do not see any option in the BIOS about legacy/compatability mode not sure what you mean by EFI media.

Comment: @user420321 - Look it up.  If you are booting in non-legacy mode then the media has to have EFI drivers on it otherwise you are required to use legacy mode.

Comment: @user420321 As you have resolved the problem, I suggest that you answer your own question. After a short while, you should be able to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a bootable Win 7 recovery USB by loading a Windows 7 ISO in VirtualBox on OS X

Answer (score 0):

I have found that some newer machines, only see an OS when it is loaded in extended bios. They seem not to see an OS if it is in Legacy. And your boot usb has to be formated so ebios not legacy sees it. The easiest way is to download OS and let MS  load it.